# PHP header reloads current page instead

Tags: php

I am trying to redirect to some page after php processing. Sometimes it works fine and it redirects to the next page but 50% of the time it just reloads the same page again.

I have tried different things like ob_clean(), ob_flush() before redirecting but it didnot work

```
function util_redirect ($page)
{
    ob_start();
    header("Location: " . $page,true,302);
    ob_end_flush();
    die(1);

}
```

Expected: redirects to the next page
Actual: Reloads current page instead

Comment: Try to keep `ob_start();` at the top of the page

Comment: keeping it at the start of the page still didnot fix the issue

Comment: even using the javascript reload script it skips it and reloads the current page

Answer (score 1):

Try this and I think this will work

```
function util_redirect ($page){
    header('Location: '.$page, TRUE, 302);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve it this way without complexity or 50% error

```
function util_redirect ($page){
   header("Location: " . $page);
}
```